# Why does element prepend removed scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a structure like

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Where the children of parent are scrollable.

If I take on of the elements from inside `parent` after scrolling.

```js
const child = parent.children[3];
```

I have a scroll position

```js
child.scrollTop; // Maybe 269px
```

And when I add it back

```js
parent.prepend(child);
```

The child looses its scroll position

```js
child.scrollTop; // 0px
```

My question here is, **why does the scroll position get lost in this case**?

[Full demonstration](https://codesandbox.io/s/element-scrolls-when-moved-to-top-in-container-3rxwsq?) of what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you `prepend(element)` it's actually first removed from the DOM then reinserted at the new position. While it's removed from the DOM, it doesn't have a CSS box anymore, no defined size, no scrolling box. When appended again all the scrolling info is reset.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("ul");
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
console.log("before", elem.scrollTop);
elem.remove();
console.log("after", elem.scrollTop);
console.log("scrollHeight", elem.scrollHeight);
console.log("height", elem.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```css
ul { max-height: 50px; overflow: scroll }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li> 
</ul>
```

Note that there is an active [discussion](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/891) to maybe add a "move" operation to the DOM APIs, but it's not quite sure yet what this would look like, nor if it would solve this use case.

If you wish to maintain the scrolling position, you'd have to store it before calling `.prepend()` and set it back after.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full demonstration I would have never understood what you were talking about.

You're moving an child. In other words you first remove it and then you insert it. Once an element is removed, `scrollTop` makes no sense and is reset.

A solution is to scroll the element down again after it has been inserted:

```
app.prepend(lastChild);
lastChild.scrollTop = lastChild.scrollHeight;
```

That seems to work fine.

Comment: `lastChild.scrollTop = lastChild.scrollHeight;` will always move the elements scroll position to the max-value. You probably want to cache the value before calling `prepend()` instead.

Comment: Although that might also be wrong, because the new position, in the DOM, that it is inserted might cause the moved node to have different dimensions.